# Use flowlayoutpanel to hold forms

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use a flowlayoutpanel to hold several forms (`public partial class SubForm : Form`). I tried:

```
SubForm sf = new SubForm ();
sf.TopLevel = false;
sf.Parent = this; // the form containing the flowLayoutPanel1
sf.Show();
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(sf); //flowLayoutPanel1 was created by the design
```

There are two problems with this:

1. I cannot "select" a SubForm. To be specific, the `Enter`, `Leave`, etc events are never triggered when I click on a SubForm in the flowLayoutPanel1
2. I cannot resize a SubForm

What I need is to create a "main" window containing several SubForms("sub" windows) in a flowlayoutpanel, I should be able to select, resize, close those "sub" windows. I'm using .Net 4.0

**Edit:**

I need to enable a user to create/delete/move/resize "sub" windows inside a "main" window, and those "sub" windows should be *automatically aligned*. That's all. If what I did is completely wrong, then please point out which specific control(s) should I use.

Comment: I've never seen someone try that before.  Enter and Leave events should work, but the form needs focusable controls inside them to make it work correctly.  There is no reason to set the Parent property.  Resizing the sub-form will probably lead to a fight with the FlowLayoutPanel's layout engine. I would re-think this type of interface — it probably won't work.

Comment: @LarsTech It's very common to have a main window containing multiple sub windows inside it, right?. A user should be able to create/delete/move/resize those sub windows. I may used the wrong controls, but do you know what I should us then?

Comment: You are describing the MDI interface.  Get rid of the FlowLayoutPanel and set the main form's IsMdiContainer property to true.  Now you just add forms to it: `sf.MdiParent = this;`  Leave TopLevel to true.

Comment: Hm. I did just what you want to do lately. My subform is a subclass of UserControl. I don't "show" the added control, I just add it to the parentPanel's controls (which in turn is on a tab etc.) I receive Enter and Leave events just fine. I even have auto resize of the parent panel after some fiddling, with scroll bars on the parent panel to keep all sub-"panels" (i.e. controls) reachable even with small main windows etc.